# SQL query find few strings in diferent columns in a table row (restrictive)

Tags: sql, sql-server, searchbar

I have a table like this one (in a SQL SERVER):

| field_name | field_descriptor | tag1 | tag2 | tag3 | tag4 | tag5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| house | your home | home | house | null | null | null |
| car | first car | car | wheel | null | null | null |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I'm developing a WIKI with a searchbar, which should be able to handle a query with more than one string for search. As an user enters a second string (spaced) the query should be able to return results that match restrictively the two strings (if exists) in any column, and so with a three string search.

Easy to do for one string with a simple SELECT with ORs.

Tried in the fronted in JS with libraries like match-sorter but it's heavy with a table with more than 100,000 results and more in the future.

I thought the query should do the heavy work, but maybe there is no simple way doing it.

Thanks in advance!

- Tried to do the heavy work with all results in frontend with filtering and other libraries like match-sorter. Works but take several seconds and blocks the front.
- Tried to create a simple OR/AND query but the posibilities with 3 search-strings (could be 1, 2 or 3) matching any column to any other possibility is overwhelming.

Comment: So, if a user enters "home wheel", do you want both rows returned because each has a match in one of the tags or don't you want any row returned, because no row maches both requested tags?

Comment: Should be restrictive! if user enters 'car wheel' it should return second row. If user enters 'car house' it should return nothing

Comment: Your table design needs normalising, do not have columns for tags, have a separate table with a single columns for tags with a FK back to your fields table. Searching is then a fast index seek into a single column.

Comment: If the tag2 of your second row is "wheels" instead of "wheel" and the user enters again "car wheel", should this still be found? Same question if it's "great wheel" or even "great wheels"...

Comment: If the search-string doesn't match exactly the columns it should be not return the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` to get a separate row per search word from the search words string. Then only select rows where all search words have a match.

The query should look like this:

```
select *
from mytable t
where exists
(
  select null
  from (select value from string_split(@search, ' ')) search
  having min(case when search.value in (t.tag1, t.tag2, t.tag3, t.tag4, t.tag5) then 1 else 0 end) = 1
);
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server seems to have a flaw (or even a bug) here and reports:

> Msg 8124 Level 16 State 1 Line 8
> Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/kNL1PVOZ

I don't have more time at hand right now, so you may use this query as a starting point to get the final query.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but string_split won't work on SQL SERVER 2014, which unfortunately is my environment!

Comment: After all, `STRING_SPLIT` is just a convenience function. The classic way to split a string in SQL is to write a recursive query where you extract the substrings in a kind of loop.

Comment: The search string is splited at the front-end and dynamically created the query, I got that covered!